# Batch Get Redirect Output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is something like

```
Input: 1 > say.bat
Output: 1
```

Possible?

Probably Not just wondering.

Also how would I get what was passed before the > sign?

If you know if it is possible or impossible, please try to comment so I don't have to wait forever.

Comment: You're going to have to go into a bit more detail about what you want. If you want to see the data that got sent to the output file, that's already in the output file. If you want to see the actual command that was run, that should already be available in the script.

Comment: I want to be able to have the output file recieve the command but not get overwritten.

Comment: Then use `>>` instead of `>` to append the output to the end of the file.

Comment: But that just writes, I don't want to write, however capture the INPUT/STDIN instead of output

Comment: Are you looking for a Windows version of Linux's `tee` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to say some text into a Batch file or any kind of file. Try these steps:

1. Use "echo" at the start of the script and then add your text you would like to output.
2. Add ">>" onto the "echo" Line and enter the file name, along with the extension of the file you would like to write to. (This will create a file if it does not exist)

For Example:

```
echo Hello World! >> file.txt
```

You will be able to use this as many times as you want.

Comment: Thanks, it is kind of hard to explain what I really wanted, but thanks.